# Concatenate 3D Numpy Arrary

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Is there a way to acheive the same output as the following code without using a for loop?

A:

```
  [[[ 1  2  3]
    [ 4  5  6]]

   [[ 7  8  9]
    [10 11 12]]]
```

Output:

```
 [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]]
```

Code:

```
A=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)

v= []
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    v.append(np.concatenate(A[i]))
```

Comment: `A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1)`? Or to get the exact same result `list(A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1))`? One remaining subtle difference: This will create views (data shared with `A`), your method copies the data.

Comment: `np.arange(24).reshape(2,12)`?

Comment: I think your sample A is off. Should start with zero and missing half the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do another reshape!

```
v = A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1)
```

It might be helpful to use the Python REPL to experiment with this in the future.